# URL not found even when the code is right

Tags: python, html, flask

I tried running this simple code on vsc

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect,url_for,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <p>hello!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

yet it still gives me a 404 error, url not found. I looked around and was quite sure that my code was right, but it still doesnt work.

I tried it with my other projects as well and it all produced the same error despite the code working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `render_template()`, index.html should be inside a folder called [`templates` next to your module.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates)

Comment: index.html is in a folder called templates already and the main.py outside of the folder

Comment: How are you running flask? and whats the exact error you are getting?

Comment: actually I realised that it is a port issue. I ran it on port 5001 and it works. Strangely when i tried to run another project on the same port (5001), it booted up my previous project. I ran the listening command to see if the ports are being used and they are apparently empty. Any thought?